# RabbitMQ get message rates for channel

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm testing how certain factors are affected when you increase the number of exchanges used. A nice statistic to have would be the message rates on a particular channel? And the transfer rate of messages from exchanges to queues if possible.

I know the RabbitMQ client application has a status command that outputs system related information, but I'm not sure if there's a utility that will allow be to query this type of information apart from the web interface.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CLI for the management interface, that may allow you to get the details you need that you can see on the web interface with out having to check it on the browser.